# What will be the mean of a conditional output

Tags: python, pandas

let's take a condition as :
(df['a'] > 10) & (df['a'] < 20)

This condition will give a true false output.
What will be the mean of this conditional output?
i.e np.mean((df['a'] > 10) & (df['a'] < 20)) = ?

Answer (score 0):

It working same like `1` and `0` values instead `True` and `False` values, so it return percentage of matched values of both conditions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[9,13,23,16,23]})

m = (df['a'] > 10) & (df['a'] < 20)
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

There is 2 matched values from 5 values, so percentage is `2/5=0.4`:

```
print (m.mean())
0.4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured it on my own too. It is basically taking the mean by adding all the 1 values and dividing it by the total numbers.

Comment: @AnubhavNehru  Exactly, just added sample to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will give the mean of all the values that is > 10 and < 20.

to get the mean value you have to use square bracket

```
np.mean(df[(df['a'] > 10) & (df['a'] < 20)])
```

Comment: No, OP need mean of mask.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I figured it on my own